# Execute and Fill Command Block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What would be the correct command to place a redstone torch at 1043 58 982 when the timer starts at 20 and remove it when the timer reaches 0 in the 1.14.2 version of Minecraft.

I think this would most likely use two different command blocks.

So far I've made a timer that starts at 20 and a Times_Up objective that equals 0.

This is the best I could come up with in a repeat command block that is always active:

```
/execute if score Timer Timer > Times_Up Times_Up run fill 1043 58 982 1043 58 982 minecraft:redstone_torch
```

Comment: …and why does that not work? It's inefficient, because `setblock` works as well, but other than that I see no problem here.

Comment: I see what you mean. It might be a problem with my scoreboard commands. Thanks!

Comment: But **I** don't see what **you** mean. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger this command at the same time as you trigger the timer, probably by using a chain command block:

```
/setblock 1043 58 982 minecraft:redstone_torch
```

It will place a redstone torch at the specified coordinates. If it isn´t possible for you to trigger any other command at the same time as you start the timer, then you can use this command in a repeating command block instead:

```
/execute if score Timer Timer > Times_Up Times_Up run setblock 1043 58 982 minecraft:redstone_torch
```

You can use this command to remove the torch if the time is up:

```
/execute if score Timer Timer <= Times_Up Times_Up run setblock 1043 58 982 air
```

Comment: I got the redstone torch to be placed, but the redstone torch does not seem to be removed when the timer hits 0 and into the negatives. Is there something I have to do with the scoreboard command blocks that I have?

Comment: I got the command blocks to work now. Thanks!